# Indexing attribute field of shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-index

Is it possible to index an attribute value of a shapefile in QGis, and if so save this as part of the project (similair to a spatial index)?

I have a large shapefile of land parcels (maybe about 1 000 000) and I would like to index them on their land parcel number so as to speed up queries on this number.

Comment: I am almost sure that it is not possible with QGIS. MapServer can be made faster by sorting dbf by one attribute with sortshp http://mapserver.org/utilities/sortshp.html. I would convert the data into SpatiaLite and create an index there.

Comment: In addition to the answer below, GIS administrators/architects/dba's/etc should really be considering alternative data structures and storage mechanisms when datasets are 1 million records. Your question is a result of poor solution design. Improve solution design and your problem doesn't happen.

Answer (score 4):

QGIS uses OGR for accessing shapefiles. Looking at the [OGR Shapefile driver page](http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html) it says

> Currently the OGR Shapefile driver only supports attribute indexes for looking up specific values in a unique key column. To create an attribute index for a column issue an SQL command of the form "CREATE INDEX ON tablename USING fieldname". To drop the attribute indexes issue a command of the form "DROP INDEX ON tablename". The attribute index will accelerate WHERE clause searches of the form "fieldname = value". The attribute index is actually stored as a mapinfo format index and is not compatible with any other shapefile applications.

So it depends on if your indexed attribute is unique.

As an alternative, you can also switch to a database like postgis, geopackage or spatialite which are designed for big data and indexing.